# Mathematical simplification of Willans' formula for the prime counting function

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-number-theorem

[Willans' formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WillansFormula.html) for the prime counting function $\pi (n)$ becomes computationally intractable for large values of $n$.  Has there been any work specifically on reducing this computational complexity, for instance by some clever trigonometric substitutions, factoring, or elimination of uninformative terms?

Comment: Willans' formula boils down to determining whether $(n-1)!+1$ is divisible by $n$; the timing for this calculation scales exponentially with $n$.